# Using Google JSAPI breaks my infieldlabel javascript, why and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jsapi

I currently have a site that both needs JSAPI and infieldlabels javascript. I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js"></script> 

<? /* those three lines for my menu */ ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" ></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" > google.load("mootools", "1.2.1"); </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/MenuMatic_0.68.3.js"></script> 

<? /* INIT */ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("label").inFieldLabels();
    });
</script>
```

However, the infield labels do not work. IF I remove the line with Google JSAPI, infield labels start working, but my menu breaks.

How do I make both work?

Comment: no error messages? check the console

Comment: I tried using it (i haven't before) but this is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/CQYsz.png

Comment: On the other console in Chrome I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'inFieldLabels'`

Comment: try loading jquery using google.load, http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html. ensure jsapi is loaded before jquery

Comment: I just tried that, yet no success :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some conflict, so I used the var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); described here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries